# How to check img src is true using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

There are 5 no. of buttons(images). 
Initially all are off image. Only 1 may be on at a time.
So when i press any button that img's src changes to on.png. Then when I press any of those on or off buttons, the pressed button source img changes to on.png and all other on img also change to off.png.

The html code is,

```
    <table cellspacing="0" style="padding:0%; margin:0% auto;">
<tr><td><img id="img1" src="off.png" height="30" width="30" onclick="off(this.id);" /></td><td>45:78</td></tr>
<tr><td><img id="img2" src="off.png" height="30" width="30" onclick="off(this.id);" /></td><td>45:78</td></tr>
<tr><td><img id="img3" src="off.png" height="30" width="30" onclick="off(this.id);" /></td><td>45:78</td></tr>
<tr><td><img id="img4" src="off.png" height="30" width="30" onclick="off(this.id);" /></td><td>45:78</td></tr>
<tr><td><img id="img5" src="off.png" height="30" width="30" onclick="off(this.id);" /></td><td>45:78</td></tr>
</table>
```

The javascript code is,

```
    function off(a)
{
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
    {
        var img = images[i];
        alert(img.src);
        if(img.src == 'on.png')
        {
            img.src = 'off.png';
        }
    }
    document.getElementById(a).src='on.png';
}
```

The if() condition is not working, Please provide solution and explain why its not

working.
Thank you!

Comment: What does the `alert` show you?

Comment: I'd suggest adding a `class`, and checking that instead of the `src`.

Comment: alert box showing one by one sources of each img tag

Answer (score 10, accepted):

img.src will return the full path of the image (/full/path/to/on.png) rather than what the src attribute is set to in the markup (on.png). Instead use:

```
if (img.getAttribute('src') === 'on.png')
```

Comment: img.src holds the full value of the image so something like: http://mysite.com/images/on.png which is not 'on.png'.

Answer (score 2):

What is the `alert(img.src);` showing? If I try on stackoverflow something like:

```
images[0].src = 'on.png';
```

`images[0].src == "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149043/on.png"`, not "on.png" (it's relative to the current page).

Comment: @deveshchauhan27 yep but is the source 'one.png' or a full path (i.e. 'http://.../one.png')? Edit: retnuh got it

Comment: full path ../img/on.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use `match`:

```
img.src.match('on.png')
```

Or with a regex (that makes sure it's at the end of the string):

```
img.src.match(/on\.png$/)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have described a behavior of radiogroup. You do not need to implement it, it is not a good practice to implement standard elements. Why you do not use something like this:

```
<radiogroup class="custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="1">
    <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="2">
    <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="3">
    <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="4">
    <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="5">
</radiogroup>
```

You can customize radiobuttons how you want, and it will work without javascript.